# why does date < 12-4-18 evaluate to false when date is set to less from 12-4-18

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my query

```
SELECT sum(paidAmount) AS payAmount
FROM Payment
where paymentDate < #12-4-18#;
```

here paymentDate = 11-4-18

Comment: Is the date the 12th of April or 4th of December?

Comment: its 12th of April.

Comment: I think your RDBMS is confused over month and day, you may need to tell it explicitly which is the month and which is the day.

Comment: may be `where  paymentDate < DATE_FORMAT('12-4-18', "%d-%m-%y")`

Comment: @MaqsoodAhmad - My point was that the DB might not know

Comment: try here https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in and sql is `SELECT * FROM Employees where birthdate < #12-8-1968#;` The result is intended. Maybe your issue is not here

Comment: @RehanAzher undefined function 'DATE_FORMAT' in expression.

Comment: which DB are u using?

Comment: i am using MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
SELECT sum(paidAmount) AS payAmount
FROM Payment
where paymentDate < Format (#12-4-18#, "dd-mm-yy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Access interprets dates as MM/DD/YYYY if possible. If you want to reliably enter a date in an SQL statement, you need to use either MM/DD/YYYY or YYYY-MM-DD as your date notation.

```
SELECT sum(paidAmount) AS payAmount
FROM Payment
where paymentDate < #2018-04-12#;
```

This of course relies on paymentDate being a valid date